# Stop Thread when user press the back button

Tags: java, android, multithreading, countdowntimer

when i press the back button, my timer is still running.

for stop thread i try:
interput() in onDestroy(), onPause() and onBackPressed() not work and i get crash

cant use and see ?! cancel() ( in Some problems like me said use Cancel() but dont know why i cant see when i press "myThread.?")

i also try to incorrect condition while loop but not solve my problem. (there was one difference with previous way which after pressed back button i saw crash my app! )

and this is my code i written:

```
counterTime = 11;

    while (counterTime > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counterTime--;
        if (txtTimer != null) {
            G.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int min = (int) Math.floor(counterTime / 60);
                    int sec = counterTime % 60;

                    String secPerfix = "";
                    if (sec < 10) {
                        secPerfix = "0";
                    }
                    txtTimer.setText(min + ":" + secPerfix + sec);

                }
            });
        }
    }

private synchronized void stopThread() {
    if (threadTimer != null){
        threadTimer.interrupt();

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    stopThread();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks modestly ok.  When you call stopThread your sending a interruptionException but your not breaking the while loop.  Do this:

```
catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//break out of the while loop and end gracefully
            break;      
  }
```

Comment: Better yet, put the try { } catch outside of the while loop

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
counterTime = 11;

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (counterTime > 0) {
                   counterTime--;
                   if (txtTimer != null) {
                      int min = (int) Math.floor(counterTime / 60);
                      int sec = counterTime % 60;
                      String secPerfix = "";
                      if (sec < 10) {
                         secPerfix = "0";
                      }
                      txtTimer.setText(min + ":" + secPerfix + sec);
                   }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 1000);
```

And on Back Pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(timertask!=null){
        timertask.cancel();
        timertask = null;
    }
    if(timer!=null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Documentation
1. [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/java/util/Timer.html)
2. [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)